# Show that the set generated by $A$ is $\{r_1a_1+r_2a_1+ \dots +r_ka_k \mid k \in \Bbb N, r_i \in R, a_i \in A, i \le k\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A$ a subset of $R$. Show that the set generated by $A$ is $\{r_1a_1+r_2a_1+ \dots +r_ka_k \mid k \in \Bbb N, r_i \in R, a_i \in A, i \le k\}.$

For the first inclusion I've picked $x \in \langle A \rangle$. This element is of form $x=a_1a_2\dots a_n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$. I don't have any ideas on how I can show that this element belongs in $\{r_1a_1+r_2a_1+ \dots +r_ka_k \mid k \in \Bbb N, r_i \in R, a_i \in A, i \le k\}$. Should I forget about showing the inclusions and use the fact that $\langle A \rangle$ is the smallest ideal that contains $A$?

Using this I have that for $x \in \langle A \rangle$, $rx \in \langle A \rangle$ and $xr \in \langle A \rangle$ for any $r \in R$. Also $\langle A \rangle$ is a subgroup of $R$ so for any $a,b \in \langle A \rangle$ we have $a+b \in \langle A \rangle$. Still I don't now how this can be used to prove the claim.

Comment: Why do you think $x=a_1 a_2 \dots a_n$? (And of course this element is of the form $r_1 a_1$, but that's irrelevant).

Comment: By definition $\langle A \rangle = \{a_1a_2a_3 \dots a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$

Comment: I think you need to re-read the definition.

Comment: The fact you are confused/not understanding is shown by the fact that you write "The *set* generated by $A$".  That would just be $A$ itself. You mean "The *ideal* generated  by $A$" and need to say so. [After all there are also "The *additive group* generated by $A$" and "The *subring* generated by $A$.] If you get that clear then I think you'll see how easy this is.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect that $x=a_1 a_2\dots a_n$. Usually the statement you want to prove is given as the definition, but in your case, I assume we define $\langle A \rangle$ to be the smallest ideal containing $A$.

If this is the case, one of the inclusions follows directly from what you wrote, i.e. the definition of an ideal. For the other inclusion, simply use the minimality of $\langle A \rangle$.